# Simplify code for dispatching different types to different functions in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I want to write a function that prints value differently for iterator types and other types. After doing some research, here is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <experimental/type_traits>

namespace details
{
    template <class T, class = void>
    struct is_iterator : std::false_type
    {
    };

    template <class T>
    struct is_iterator<T, std::experimental::void_t<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>> : std::true_type
    {
    };

    template <class T>
    constexpr auto is_iterator_v = is_iterator<T>::value;
}

template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<!details::is_iterator_v<T>> print(const T &value)
{
    std::cout << value;
}

template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<details::is_iterator_v<T>> print(const T &value)
{
    std::cout << "(IteratorTo ";
    print(*value);
    std::cout << ')';
}
```

But I think my code is a little too long and a little complicated. Is it possible to make my code shorter and cleaner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) is your friend here:

```
template<class T>
constexpr std::true_type is_iterator(typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type*, int) {
    return {};
}

template<class T>
constexpr std::false_type is_iterator(void*, long) {
    return {};
}

template<class T>
constexpr auto is_iterator_v = is_iterator<T>(nullptr, 0);
```

Also, an alternative implementation of `print` using tag-dispatching, which you may or may not find more readable:

```
template<class T>
void print(const T &);

namespace details {
    template<class T>
    void print(const T &value, std::false_type) {
        std::cout << value;
    }

    template<class T>
    void print(const T &value, std::true_type) {
        std::cout << "(IteratorTo ";
        print(*value);
        std::cout << ')';
    }
}

template<class T>
void print(const T &value) {
    details::print(value, details::is_iterator_v<T>);
}
```

Comment: @aschepler : Fair points all! Shameless laziness on my part. >_>

Comment: @ildjarn - nice solution (+1); never thought the `int`/`long` trick to solve the ambiguity problem when `T` is an iterator; but what about the signature of the last `print()` in the last example? Shouldn't be `void print (const T &value)` without the `std::true_type`?

Comment: @max66 : Indeed, sloppy copy/paste error on my part. Thanks

Comment: Upvoted, I strongly think though that tag dispatching should be the preferred solution here. The length of the code is not as important as the fact that the user-facing interface is clean, and contained in a single function signature.

Comment: @ildjarn - sorry, not seen before but... in `print(const T&)`, shoudn't be `details::print(value, details::is_iterator_v<T>);` instead of `details::print(T, details::is_iterator_v<T>);` (I mean: `value` instead of `T`)? And another question: there is a reason because, in the `std::false_type` version of `is_iterator()`, the type of the first argument is `void const volatile *` and not `void const *` or simply `void *`?

Comment: @ildjarn - an aesthetical doubt: now that you have removed the `.value` part from `is_iterator_v` definition (that is: now that `is_iterator_v` is a type and no more a value), isn't better name it `is_iterator_t` instead `is_iterator_v`? And a syntactic doubt: `details::print(value, details::is_iterator_v<T>{})` instead `details::print(value, details::is_iterator_v<T>)` ?

Comment: @max66 : `is_iterator_v` is a value – a constexpr object of either type `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`. That object is then implicitly convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @max66 : No problem. Thanks for all the feedback, this answer needed a lot of cleanup. :-S

Answer (score 0):

I find your solution simple, short and clean.

I see only a problem: you tagged your question C++14 but you propose code that use `std::experimental::void_t` that is... well... experimental and not ever available.

But (if I'm not wrong), you could obtain the same result also without `void_t`, using the old decltype comma trick.

You can write your `std::true_type` version as follows (modified trying to correct a problem pointed by Ildjarn (thanks!)):

```
template <typename T>
struct is_iterator<T,
   decltype(std::declval<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>(),
      void())> : std::true_type
 { };
```

This solution should work with C++11 too.

Comment: This requires that `value_type` is default-constructible; quite a strong requirement!

Comment: @ildjarn - D'oh! You're right. Too strong requirement. Correct me if I'm wrong: `std::declval` is supposed to solve this problem, isn't it? (see my modified answer)